# Cordova/Phoengap resolveLocalFileSystemURL Error 5

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've upgraded this app from approx a year ago and it has broken the cordova file system section.

Essentially, I can no longer get `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` (was previously `resolveLocalFileSystemUR**I**` but that's no longer supported) to retrieve my photos. It always ends up in the error call back with an error code of 5 or 1 (depending on prefixes as explained below)

Below is the code and I've commented relevant outputs from debug alerts:

```
function takePicture() {
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onGetPictureFail,
                { quality: 75, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, correctOrientation: true });
            return true;
        }



function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
        createFileEntry(imageURI);
    }

    function onGetPictureFail(error) {
        fileFail(error);
    }
    function createFileEntry(imageURI) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, movePhoto, fileFail);
    }

    function movePhoto(fileEntry) {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
            function (fileSys) {
                //onsuccess
                fileSys.root.getDirectory("FotoscanPhotos", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (dir) {
                    //Here dir is as follows:
                    //isFile: false,
                    //isDirectory: true,
                    //name: FotoscanPhotos,
                    //fullPath: "//FotoscanPhotos/",
                    //fileSystem: <FileSystem: persistent>,
                    //nativeURL: "file:///storage/emulated/0/FotoscanPhotos/"
                    fileEntry.moveTo(dir, (guid + "foto.jpg"), onMoveSuccess, fileFail);
                }, fileFail);
            }, fileFail);
    }


    function onMoveSuccess(entry) {
        var image = { ean: ean, image: '/' + entry.fullPath, timestamp: convertDateToUTC(), displayTime: displayTime(), size: entry.size };
        images.push(image);
        Speicher.setImages(images);
    }
```

And here is where the problem comes in:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(localURI, function (fileEntry) {
 //localURI comes in as /FotoscanPhotos/filename.jpg though I have also        
 //tried it with the following prefixes: "file:/" and "file://" and "file:"
 }, resolveFileSystemError);
```

I'm doing this for Android but no particular phone and no guarantee of the use of external storage (SDCards). So I'm trying to get this right without the use of any hardcoding where at all possible.

It seems to me that there's an issue with relative paths and the missing storage place prefix perhaps?

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Rory

Answer (score 0):

Switching to NativeURL seems to do the trick

Comment: can u explain how ??

Comment: @KishanOza it' been over a year since I've worked on phonegap and no longer have access to the code I was working on so can't help you out I'm afraid

Comment: that's ok sonice to see your reply comes :)